# Conectarse a una instancia de Google cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform

La plataforma Google cloud provee de una línea de comandos para administrar las instancias o máquinas virtuales que se creen, por medio de esta línea de comandos, cuál es el comando para conectarse a una instancia en particular, tengo creada la instancia 1 ,2 ,  3,
Así que debe haber un comando que indique.
Gcloud instance instancia1, para conectarse a está en particular.

Comment: ¿No te sirve conectarte a una instancia por SSH?

Answer (score 3):

Entiendo que tienes diversas instancias de Google Compute Engine en tu proyecto de GCP, y quieres acceder a ellas. Puedes hacerlo siguiendo la información proporcionada en la documentación para [Conectarse a Instancias de GCE](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance).

El comando de `gcloud` que debes utilizar para conectar a una instancia de GCE (llamémosla `instancia1`) es el siguiente:

```
gcloud compute ssh instancia1
```

Puedes ejecutar este comando desde la Cloud Shell, o desde cualquier otro sitio en el que tengas instalado el Cloud SDK.

Por otro lado, puedes dirigirte directamente a la pestaña de "Compute Engine > Instancias" en la Consola, y usar el botón de `SSH` al lado de la instancia de GCE, lo cual abrirá una nueva ventana con el acceso a la instancia vía SSH.